# JVM hs_err.log not being generated on Linux

Tags: java, linux, hs-err

I'm currently having some issues with a Java application I'm developing. Namely the JVM is crashing with a segfault. I'm trying to locate the hs_err.log file which should contain some helpful info about the issue.

However, I can't find this file. I've used find, locate, etc, and nothing.

Any ideas on why the log file isn't being generated?

Answer (score 7):

I think the file is called `"hs_err_pid<pid>.log"` where `<pid>` is the process id of the crashed JVM process.

The following comes from the [JDK 5 Troubleshooting Guide](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/jdk50_ts_guide.pdf).

> When a fatal error occurs an error log is created in the file `hs_err_pid<pid>.log` (where `<pid>` is
>   the process id of the process). Where possible the file is created in the working directory of the
>   process. In the event that the file cannot be created in the working directory (insufficient space,
>   permission problem, or other issue) then the file is created in the temporary directory for the operating
>   system. On Solaris and Linux the temporary directory is /tmp. On Windows the temporary directory
>   is specified by the value of the TMP environment variable, or if that is not defined, the value of the
>   TEMP environment variable.

Also lookup the `-XX:ErrorFile=...` option listed in the [Hotspot Specific JVM Options](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/hotspot/vmoptions.jsp).

Comment: I know, I searched for "hs_err*", so it should find it anyway. I'll try the -XX:ErroFile option. Thanks.

Comment: *"I know, I searched for "hs_err*", so it should find it anyway."* - That depends on whether 1) the file actually exists, 2) you searched the right place,  and 3) you implemented the search correctly.

Comment: It could sometimes be that the JVM gets too badly corrupted, e.g. by an invalid address from JNI, to do the job. I have failed to get an `hs_err_*` after calling `JNIEnv->FatalError()` after an unhandleable  Java exception, which you would think would do it! — That’s what brought me here.